# how to undo the damage from a botched check-in after a tortoisesvn 'move'?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I screwed up a 'move', and now I don't know how to undo the damage.

I moved a folder 'x' from one parent to another, i.e. 'dir1/x' --> 'dir2/x'.  I should then have checked in both dir1 and dir2 at the same time.  But I didn't.  I checked in only dir2.

As a separate step, I then tried checking in dir1, but got a 'tree conflict' error.  I then deleted dir1/x and did a cleanup/update on the parent dir1.  That left me with a yellow exclamation mark on dir1 (when viewed within windows explorer).  When I try to check in dir1, Tortoisesvn lists the text-status of 'x' as 'missing'.  The check-in doesn't show any error, but no files/folders get changed and the yellow exclamation mark remains.

I then restored dir1/x and did a cleanup and update on dir1/x.  But when I try to check in dir1/x I get an error "remains in tree-conflict".

Anyone know how to unscrew-up my screw-up?

UPDATE:  Problem solved.  Here is what I did to resolve the tree-conflict:

1. I right-clicked on the parent of dir1 and dir2 and selected "check for modifications"
2. I then right-clicked on the missing folder, x, which was highlighted in red, and selected "edit tree conflicts".
3. I then clicked on "mark the conflict as resolved"

I found this reference helpful:  http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html